# Storing and using multiple values on ember select

Tags: ember.js

I have this jsbin : http://jsbin.com/IYUSiLUz/1/edit

in here you can select a value in the select, and it shows the selected value in the form. You can also set the default value, and that selection will be highlighted by default in the select.

How can I achieve the same result for a multiple select ? If you change multiple=true, what do you need to change to highlight two items (for example) in the select, and how do you get the selected values ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selection` property of `Ember.Select` to get a list of all the selected objects:

```
{{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="App.data"
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    optionLabelPath="content.personName" 
    valueBinding="App.demo"
    selectionBinding="selected"
    multiple=true }}

{{#each selected}}
  {{input value=id}}
{{/each}}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/IYUSiLUz/7/edit